# Javascript/Node.js Calculating Programs current CPU usage

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hey there, I'm trying to find out if there's a way to get how much of the CPU(percentage) is being used by the running script using Node.js. I know there is a way to find the computers current CPU usage, as seen in other posts, but I can't seem to find if there is a way to get the scripts CPU usage and figured I'd ask here.

To be as specific as possible, say your computer is at 60% CPU usage, I want the program to check how much (x) of 60 it is using and then return that information to an algorithm or var.

Comment: What have you done so far? No code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get the process ID of current running Node.js Script

```
var process = require('process');
var processId = process.pid;
```

And execute this command to get the cpu usage.

```
if (processId) {
    var output = system("ps up " + processId + " | tail -n1 | tr -s ' ' | cut -f3 -d' '");
}
```